# What is the easiest way to make editForm in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my database i have many users which has many recipes.
Every recipe has some properties and collection of ingredients.
Below is screenshot

[Recipe with all properties](https://ibb.co/MShhqDy)

So when user display recipe to edit on page should appear (form) recipe with loaded current data. This is kind of working because i can see the data but i think it's no done good.

I have form which is working fine without array (ingredients). Could you tell me how i should add ingredients to my edit form?

I'd be grateful if you see at my code and give me feedback and hints what i should change.

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editForm') editForm: NgForm;
  recipe: IRecipe;
  photos: IPhoto[] = [];
  ingredients: IIngredient[] = [];
  uploader: FileUploader;
  hasBaseDropZoneOver = false;
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  
  currentMain: IPhoto;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private recipeService: RecipeService,
    private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadRecipe();  
  }

  loadRecipe() {
    this.recipeService.getRecipe(this.route.snapshot.params.id).subscribe(recipe => {
      this.recipe = recipe;
      this.initializeUploader();
    })
  }
  updateRecipe(id: number) {
    this.recipeService.editRecipe(id, this.recipe).subscribe(next => {
      this.toastr.success('Recipe updated successfully');
      this.editForm.reset(this.recipe);
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error(error);
    });
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container mt-4 border" *ngIf="recipe">
    <form #editForm="ngForm" id="editForm" (ngSubmit)="updateRecipe(recipe.id)" >
      <h5 class=" text-center mt-2">Recipe details:</h5>
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
          <label for="city">Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="recipe.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <app-ingredient-editor [ingredients] = "recipe.ingredients"></app-ingredient-editor>
          <div *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index">

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.name}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.amount}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <br>
          <p>Add recipes</p>
        </div>
      <h5 class=" text-center mt-4">Description</h5>
        <angular-editor cols=100% rows="6" [placeholder]="'Your description'" [(ngModel)]="recipe.description"  name="description"></angular-editor>
    </form>  

    <button [disabled]="!editForm.dirty" form="editForm" class="btn btn-success btn-block mb-5 mt-5">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

For now it's look like:

[Form on page](https://ibb.co/3pPtLQc)

When i delete ingredient name while changing on the console i have following error:

```
recipe-edit.component.html:12 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
```

Problem is that part of code:

```
 <div *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index">
    
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.name}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ingredient.amount}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount">
              </div>
            </div>
```

But i don't know how to make it working..

**How to add add array to template-driven form?**
**In my case i need to display current ingredients and be able to edit them.**

I have tried something like this :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="ingredient[i].name" [(ngModel)]="ingredient[i].name">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ingredient[i].amount" [(ngModel)]="ingredient[i].amount">
```

But id doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the property `name` on the form must be defined in order for angular to know which input to update. You're binding name to the same property that the editable model is set to which means the user can edit it and in fact delete it, which isn't good.

The solution is to change it to a unique value that doesn't change. This should work:

```html
<div *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name{{ingredient.id}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amount{{ingredient.id}}" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount">
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to stackblitz showing it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-base-template-q243lw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Edit: fixed bug in original post and added link to stackblitz

Comment: Currently i have 2 ingredients. If i'm using your solution on page i have 4 fields only with amount? "You're binding name to the same property that the editable model is set to which means the user can edit it and in fact delete it. - this is what i want to do !

Comment: I don't understand why your user should need to edit the name of the input field. That's simply an identifier so angular knows which field to update. What should matter is editing the value and that is done via ngmodel

Comment: Ok I found the bug in my original post. Each field needs a unique ID and I was assigning the same id to both the name and the amount field. I updated my answer which includes a link to a stackblitz showing it working

Comment: Your solution solved that problem, but when i update recipe inside that method is executed this.editForm.reset(this.recipe) and form is reseting. Values: Name, Description are visible but fields with ingredients are empty. Do you know why?

Comment: `reset` will clear any inputs. Name and description aren't cleared because they're not inputs, they're just hard-coded text in the code. I guess I'm not really sure what the desired effect is